# Excel Addin - update data of newly created workbook

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I am working on an Excel addin, which allows users to open some predefined files. I have opened selected file using **Excel.createWorkbook**. Now I need to update values of some cells in the templates based on user information, for example user name, full name, department etc. I have done this using code below (copied from examples in documentation)

```
                    const reader = new FileReader();

                    reader.onload = (event) => {
                        Excel.run((context) => {
                            // Remove the metadata before the base64-encoded string.
                            const startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
                            const mybase64 = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);

                            Excel.createWorkbook(mybase64);
                            return context.sync();
                        });
                    };

                    //Read in the file as a data URL so we can parse the base64-encoded string.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
```

Now I want to access newly created workbook and update cells. But I am unable to find a class/function/object which I can use to get sheet/range. Can someone guide me about it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your scenario, there is no way to do this in an Office Add-in. With very few exceptions, an Office Add-in lives in a world where there is only one Office document: the one that is currently open. The add-in that is running in the current document can create a new document, but the add-in cannot interact with the content of that new document because add-in is not running in that new document.

I think the closest you could come is this:

1. Design the add-in task pane to have two tabs: one for creating new workbooks and a second for interacting with the current document.
2. Instruct users to use the first tab to create a new workbook.
3. Instruct users to open the new workbook, if it doesn't open automatically, install the add-in, and open the second tab.
4. Users can then use the add-in's second tab to interact with the new workbook.